# Can't mount Windows NTFS partition from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, mount, ntfs

I'm helping a friend with their Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 installed. A fake "Microsoft Tech Support" person enabled SysKey Startup Password so that they get a password prompt when they try to log onto their computer.

I've found some older articles that suggest using programs to disable Startup Password. To do so, I have to copy the hives from the infected computer over to a temp work area on a different machine, run the utility on the files, and then copy them back to the problematic machine. For example, see this article: [SOLUTION: “This is Microsoft Support” telephone scam – Computer ransom lockout](http://triplescomputers.com/blog/casestudies/solution-this-is-microsoft-support-telephone-scam-computer-ransom-lockout/)

I have been able to boot the Surface using Ubuntu 14.10 on a USB drive. However, I can't mount the C:\ partition. Here is the info from `fdisk`:

```
/dev/sda4 1390592 489263103 487872512 232.7G Microsoft basic data
```

When I try to mount the partition, I get an error: "The device '/dev/sda4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS".

Is there any way to mount to this drive within Linux? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try addendum A in that link you posted?

Comment: I burned to a thumb drive but the thumb drive won't boot on the Surface Pro.  I was able to boot the thumb drive from a laptop, however.  I'm trying the section below the article which is to copy the files from the Surface Pro.

Comment: Refer to [AskUbuntu - Can't mount NTFS drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548417/cant-mount-ntfs-drive).

Comment: If that doesn't resolve the issue, please provide more details, especially the exact error message you get when trying to mount.

Comment: What is the mount command you're using?